# Bash function only works when password manually input

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, expect

At work I have to run the following function everyday. The function works fine when I am prompted for the password. However, I tried to hardcode my password so that I don't have to enter it in each day. This doesn't work. Any hints on why?

```
function update()
{
  firewalluser=`whoami`
  # -s => silent (no echo of characters), -p => prompt user
  #read -s -p "Password: " firewallpass                                         
  firewallpass="mypassword"                                                     
  TRUSTED=(
    xxx.yyy.com
    jenkins.xxx.com
    svn.xxx.com
  )
  for server in ${TRUSTED[*]}
  do
    echo ""
    echo "--> connecting to $server"
    expect <<EOF                                                                
      set timeout 20                                                            
      spawn telnet $server                                                      
      expect "Username: "                                                       
      send "$firewalluser\r"                                                    
      expect "Password: "                                                       
      send "$firewallpass\r"                                                    
      expect "Firewall User Authentication: Accepted"                           
      send "exit"                                                               
      exit                                                                      
EOF                                                                             
  done
}
```

I'm running this in `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)` with the function defined in my `.bash_profile`.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I added `exp_internal 1` and here is the response from program:

```
--> connecting to some.domain.name.com
spawn telnet some.domain.name.com
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {64289}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Username: "? no
Trying xx.yy.zz...

expect: does "Trying xx.yy.zz...\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Username: "? no
Connected to some.domain.name.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

expect: does "Trying xx.yy.zz...\r\nConnected to some.domain.name.com.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Username: "? no
Please Authenticate to VSD DR2
Username:
expect: does "Trying xx.yy.zz...\r\nConnected to some.domain.name.com.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nPlease Authenticate to VSD DR2\r\nUsername: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pa\
tern "Username: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Username: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying xx.yy.zz...\r\nConnected to some.domain.name.com.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nPlease Authenticate to VSD DR2\r\nUsername: "
send: sending "nklosterman\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password: "? no

Password:
expect: does "\r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nPassword: "
send: sending "mypassword!\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Firewall User Authentication: Accepted"? no

Firewall User Authentication: Failed

expect: does "\nFirewall User Authentication: Failed\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Firewall User Authentication: Accepted"? no
Connection closed by foreign host.

expect: does "\nFirewall User Authentication: Failed\r\nConnection closed by foreign host.\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Firewall User Authentication: Accepted"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\nFirewall User Authentication: Failed\r\nConnection closed by foreign host.\r\n"
send: sending "exit" to { exp7 send: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
    "send "exit""
```

I can see my password being sent with the \r appended to it. I'm not sure why it isn't accepting it. I even tried hardcoding my password in the heredoc instead of setting the variable and this didn't work.

Comment: Generally requests for passwords don't go through standard I/O, so input cannot be redirected, and commands like `echo password|su` don't work. I don't know the `expect` program, but it looks as though it works by reading and writing other programs' dialogues by redirecting their I/O through pipes. In `ftp` you can put passwords (in plain text!) into the `.netrc` initialisation file, and I successfully automate FTP transfers using this, but I don't know that `.telnetrc` allows the same.

Comment: Problem appears to be with `expect`, from what I've read it should be capable of using passwords in this manner. And, is your work's IT dept / boss happy about having passwords stored in plain text?

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the expect script before `set timeout`. That will turn on verbose debugging so you can see what expect is doing with the password.

Comment: @Xen2050 Concerning the security aspect, I agree this is a serious security concern. However, this place assigns passwords and reuses them(!) such that coworkers can guess your password quite easily. Therefore I think that a plaintext password in a script is the least of the gaping holes to worry about!

Comment: Are you sure that you have to add `\r` in `send "$firewalluser\r"` and `send "$firewallpassword\r"` ? In other examples I've seen only `send "$user "`...

Answer (score 0):

It look like a carriage return vs newline issue.

Your active terminal might not be matching the remote system and some automatic translation might be wrong. You can compare both system using the *stty(1)* command.

From the *Expect* documentation:

> In this case, when you press return, it will be translated to a newline. If Expect then  passes  that to a program which sets its terminal to raw mode (like telnet), there is going to be a problem, as the program expects a true return.
>
> Rather than manually replacing newlines with returns, the solution is to use the command "stty raw", which will stop the translation.  Note, however, that this means that you will no longer get the cooked line-editing features.

I suggest you try replacing the `\r` with `\n` in your code. If that still doesn't work, it might need both `\r\n` to work. If it still doesn't work you'll have to troubleshoot the terminal mode of both system and what happen to the carriage returns and newlines as they go back and forth.

Also, this assume you have the right passwords of course! ;)